# How would I optimise this Perl regex?

Tags: regex, perl

I wrote this regex a while ago which fixes invalid/broken XML, but it's really slow, what should i do to make it faster?

```
s/(.*?>)([^>.]*?&[^\#a].*?)</$1<!\[CDATA\[$2\]\]></ismg;
```

Sample input data showing the part that it fixes, note that the entire XML has other elements and has more data in it.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><sample>
<test id="123" data="text">&#209;ucastle & Tyne</test>
<test id="123" data="text">Rock & Roll</test>
<test id="123" data="text">Peanut & Butter</test>
<test id="123" data="text">Ice & Cream</test></sample>
```

Sample output data:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><sample>
<test id="123" data="text"><![CDATA[&#209;ucastle & Tyne]]></test>
<test id="123" data="text"><![CDATA[Rock & Roll]]></test>
<test id="123" data="text"><![CDATA[Peanut & Butter]]></test>
<test id="123" data="text"><![CDATA[Ice & Cream]]></test></sample>
```

Comment: Could you please provide some example data?

Comment: Replace `.*?` with something more precise.

Comment: Hi Vadim, I added a sample xml file now.

Comment: replace the leading `(.*?>)` with just `>`; less matching to do

Comment: Wait, do you really want `&#209;ucastle & Tyne` for `<![CDATA[&#209;ucastle & Tyne]]`? My solution doesn't do that.

Comment: I don't think so, no. Actually, I can't remember if unicode needs to be wrapped in a cdata tag, as long as it is valid xml, I can convert it all later. I just need it to be valid xml so I can parse it.

Comment: s/unicode/html entities/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Newcastle <![CDATA[&]]> Tyne` or just `Newcastle &amp; Tyne` would be equivalent. That means we don't need to locate the start and end of the text node. We don't even need to check if we are in a text node because `&` should be escaped in attribute values too. So all you need is:

```
s/&(?!#|[a-zA-Z]+;)/&amp;/g;
```

No backtracking. No captures. There's nothing to slow it down.

Tried against your test data:

```
$ cat >file.xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><sample>
<test id="123" data="text">Newcastle & Tyne</test>
<test id="123" data="text">Rock & Roll</test>
<test id="123" data="text">Peanut & Butter</test>
<test id="123" data="text">Ice & Cream</test></sample>

$ perl -pe's/&(?!#|[a-zA-Z]+;)/&amp;/g' file.xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><sample>
<test id="123" data="text">Newcastle &amp; Tyne</test>
<test id="123" data="text">Rock &amp; Roll</test>
<test id="123" data="text">Peanut &amp; Butter</test>
<test id="123" data="text">Ice &amp; Cream</test></sample>
```

Usage:

```
perl -pe's/&(?!#|[a-zA-Z]+;)/&amp;/g' in.xml >out.xml
perl -i~ -pe's/&(?!#|[a-zA-Z]+;)/&amp;/g' file.xml     # In-place, with backup
perl -i -pe's/&(?!#|[a-zA-Z]+;)/&amp;/g' file.xml      # In-place, no backup
```

Comment: Nice, I'm just trying to think of a reason why I didn't replace it with &amp; before.

Comment: I think it was because I couldn't figure out how to differentiate between & followed by another character that would make it a unicode char e.g. &#123, and & with a whitespace. I can't recall exactly.